# Why very slow / no directory caching with SSHFS?

Tags: linux, bash, mount, fstab, sshfs

I have the below in `/etc/fstab` and when I `cd ~/dat0` and then do anything in there e.g. tab complete, it takes 10 seconds every time. I.e. it doesn't cache anything.

Is there something that can be done to speed this up?

```
ss@dat0: /home/ss/dat0 fuse.sshfs defaults,_netdev,identityfile=/home/ss/.ssh/id_rsa,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other 0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

What system are you on? What versions of sshfs and fuse are you running?
I'm on ubuntu server 18.04 and using authorized keys for auth.

This my fstab:

```
sshfs#user@server:/var/path/  /home/user/path  fuse defaults,allow_other,uid=111,gid=115,noauto 0   0
```

and versions:

```
fuse             2.9.7-1ubuntu1  amd64    
libfuse2:amd64   2.9.7-1ubuntu1  amd64
sshfs            2.8-1           amd64
```

Here's some output from timing ls -l

```
$ time ls -l | wc -l
1259

real    0m0.160s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.012s
```

A remote directory with 1259 files or folders listed pretty quickly.

I don't know if it may make a difference or not but I also have:

```
UseDNS no
```

In my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. It speeds up initial logins